# lodash extend not extending knockout observable

Tags: knockout.js, lodash

I have an observable:

```
user.profile = {
  name: ko.observable();
}
```

I want to add another observable property to it:

```
_.extend(user.profile,{email:ko.observable('email@foo.com')});
```

Then when I do `user.profile()` it only shows the name property.

Comment: `user.profile()`  wouldn't work at all because `user.profile` isn't a function or observable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look, maybe you dont see the modification becouse you are working with js object not with  `ko.observable`, so if you see in the snippet it works fine.

```js
function viewModel(){
  var user= {}
  user.profile = {
     name:ko.observable("teste")
  };
  this.profile = ko.observable(user.profile);     
 };

viewModel.prototype.extend= function(){
  this.profile(_.extend(this.profile(),{email:ko.observable('email@foo.com')}));
};
ko.applyBindings( new viewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>


<span data-bind="text:ko.toJSON(profile)"></span>

<button data-bind="click: extend">Extend</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

If `user.profile` is an observable, your assignment above is misleading. It would be

```
user.profile({name: ko.observable()});
```

If that's the case, it would make sense that lodash doesn't extend it as expected. It would be adding a member to the observable, not to the observable's contents. You would have `user.profile.email`. You might get the results you want by trying

```
_.extend(user.profile(), {email:ko.observable('email@foo.com')});
```

although I'm not sure what this buys you over just

```
user.profile().email = ko.observable('email@foo.com');
```